# Find the area of the region bounded by the following curves.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the area of the region bounded by the following curves.

$f(x)=x^2+x−27$, $g(x)=−x^2+5x+3$

I know I need to put the equations together and factor them to gets
x= -3, 5

$\int^5_{-3}(x^2+x−27)-(x^2+5x+3)$

But after that I am lost, does anyone know what I need to do after to get the answer? It should be round to 3 decimal points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region is given below.
[image]

You solved correctly the points of intersection. But your formula for the area is not correct. This is how to solved it.
$$\begin{align}
A&=\int_{-3}^5\big[g(x)-f(x)\big]dx\\\
&=\int_{-3}^5\bigg[(-x^2+5x+3)-(x^2+x-27)\bigg]dx\\
&=\int_{-3}^5(-2x^2+4x+30)dx\\
&=\bigg[-\frac{2x^3}{3}+2x^2+30x\bigg]_{-3}^5\\
&=\bigg(-\frac{250}{3}+50+150\bigg)-\bigg(18+18-90\bigg)\\
&=-\frac{250}{3}+200+54\\
&=\frac{512}{3}
\end{align}$$